# New users appearing on reputation leagues have total reputation less than year reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

I've noticed that users who were not previously ranked on the [philosophy reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/265/year/philosophy/2019-01-01/29944#29944) have total reputation less than their year reputation.  Here is an example:

[image]

I imagine this should be at least their year reputation. This appears to be the case for quarter as well, but not for week and month.

Comment: caching! it's always caching!